# Angular 2 download json response data from getList() in csv or Excel format

Tags: json, angular, csv, get, response

The end game is simple, my Angular app gets and generates a list of data entries on a view called `customers-list.component.html` like so:

```
Name:  Olivia
Age:  23
Active:  true

----------------
Name:  Julia
Age:  22
Active:  true

----------------
Name:  Wes
Age:  23
Active:  true

----------------
Name:  Gabe
Age:  24
Active:  false
```

I want to be able to download a `.csv` file of said entries of data.

In the `customers-list.component.ts`, I've tried this function `getcsvFile()`, defined the data that is passed in through the `service.ts`, defined a new `Blob()` function and used `JSON.stringify(data)` and passed in `getCustomersList()` data and save it as a `.csv`:

```
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Observable<Customer[]>;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }
...... 
 getcsvFile() {

      this.customers = this.customerService.getCustomersList();
      let file = new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.customers)], { type: 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,content_encoded_as_url' });
      saveAs(file, 'customerList.csv')
    }

}
```

Heres the service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/customers';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
.........
  getCustomersList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/`);
  }
}
```

but when I download the csv file and open it, i dont see the actual data thats been entried, but rather all this weird information thats still in json format:

```
{
"_isScalar":false,
"source":{"_isScalar":false,
"source":{"_isScalar":false,
"source":{"_isScalar":true,
"value":{"url":"http://localhost:8000/customers/",
"body":null,"reportProgress":false,
"withCredentials":false,
"responseType":"json",
"method":"GET",
"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},
"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},
"params":{"updates":null,
"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},
"map":null},
"urlWithParams":"http://localhost:8000/customers/"}},
"operator":{"concurrent":1}},
"operator":{}},
"operator":{}
}
```

when i want to see something closer to this :

```
[
{"id": 2, "name": "Olivia", "age": 23, "active": true}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "Julia", "age": 22, "active": true}, 
{"id": 4, "name": "Wes", "age": 23, "active": true}, 
{"id": 5, "name": "Gabe", "age": 24, "active": false}
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: use ngx-papaparse https://alberthaff.dk/projects/ngx-papaparse/docs/v3/generating-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be interesting to see what your `saveAs` function does, but anyhow, if you do not want to install a module, you can easily do it yourself.

```
  // Download CSV
download(data: any, filename: string, columns: string, header: string, delimiter: string | undefined) {
  const csvData = this.convertToCSV(data, columns, header, delimiter);
  const link: any = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  const blob = new Blob([csvData], {type: 'text/csv'});
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const isIE = !!(<any> document).documentMode;

  if (isIE) {
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename + '.csv');
  } else {
    link.download = filename + '.csv';
  }
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```

and to transform your JSON into a CSV, you can do it like that:

```
/**
 * exports json (array) data to CSV
 * @param data
 * @param {string} columns
 * @param {string} header
 * @param {string | undefined} delimiter
 * @returns {string}
  */
  convertToCSV(data: any, columns: string, header: string, delimiter: string | 
undefined) {
  let row = '';
  const del = delimiter ? delimiter : ';';
  const head = header.split(del);
  const col = columns.split(del);

  // creating the header
  for (const headerTxt of head) {
    row += headerTxt + del;
  }
  row += '\r\n';
  //  start with the rows
  for (const dataset of data) {
    let line = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      let dataToAdd = dataset[col[i]];
      if (dataset[col[i]] == null || dataset[col[i]] === undefined) {
        dataToAdd = '';
      }
      line += '"' + dataToAdd + '"' + del;
    }
    row += line + '\r\n';
  }
  return row;
}
```

so in your case you would most likely call it like that:

```
download(this.customers, 'customer', 
'id,name,age,active', 
'ID,Name,Age,Active', ',')
```

Hope that helps :)

Edit:

I see, you are not subscribing your observable, that most likely is the error. Try this:

```
 getcsvFile() {

    this.customerService.getCustomersList()
     .pipe(take(1)) // <-- HERE 
     .subscribe(customers=>{ // <-- AND HERE
      if (customers) {
        download(customers, 'customer','id,name,age,active','ID,Name,Age,Active', ',');
      }
   });

}
```

Greetings

Comment: saveAs is imported from file-saver module 

import * as saveAs from 'file-saver';
also where am i suppose to put those methods? because it keeps saying undefined when I try to call it from the getcsvFile() method

Comment: its also giving off this error from the convertToCsv() method :

CustomersListComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at CustomersListComponent.push../src/app/customers-list/customers-list.component.ts.CustomersListComponent.convertToCSV (customers-list.component.ts:62)
    at

Comment: also giving off this ERRORTypeError: header.split is not a function
    at CustomersListComponent.push../src/app/cust 
when i call it like this
  getcsvFile() {

      this.customers = this.customerService.getCustomersList();
      let file = new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.customers)], { type: 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,content_encoded_as_url' });
      this.convertToCSV(file, 'customer',
['id', 'name', 'age', 'active'],
['ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Active'], ',')
      download(file, 'customer',
['id', 'name', 'age', 'active'],
['ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Active'], ',')
    }

Comment: ah thanks, but im still getting this ERRORTypeError: header.split is not a function at  
line 62 --------------------------> const head = header.split(del);

Comment: yeah, thats right, that could not have worked, updated it accordingly

Comment: EDIT: so for some reason its NOT accepting split as a function

Comment: it works! thank you so much for responding and being a big help in helping me solve this :] !